# Is there a predefined function available to delete every element of an array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to delete every element of an array in PHP using a predefined function

i have already tried the reset function which only set the internal pointer of an array to its first element and i have also done the task by using a for loop

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
for ($i=count($arr); $i > 0 ; $i--) { 
   array_pop($arr);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `$arr = [];` do the same thing?

Comment: Why don't you set your array to an empty array i.e: `$arr = [];`?

Comment: Thanks for you response sir

Comment: I never though of that sir, i now have my answer

Answer (score 1):

As already said in comments - deleting all elements in array means that you will have an empty array, so just:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
$arr = [];
```

Also, `unset($a);` can be used, but after `unset` usage of `$arr` variable will throw **undefined variable** notice.

Comment: `unset`  i think not works for this, i think you have remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to empty the array indirectly:

```
<?php

$sports = array("Baseball", "Cricket", "Football", "Shooting");
 
// Deleting All Elements From array Sports
$sports = array();   //Just Set the empty array to your var.

print_r($sports);

?>
```

Above Example:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f6sj-zhki

For Your Example:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hu17-7bnk

Answer (score 0):

I have got the simplest method of doing the task

```
$arr = []
```